# application using ffmpeg segfaults because of for loop?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, segmentation-fault, libavformat

I am writing my first ffmpeg application using the tutorial linked to from the ffmpeg.org documentation page [[tutorial](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/)] [[sample](https://github.com/mpenkov/ffmpeg-tutorial)]. Here is my initial code:

```
const char * fnmVideoIn = argv [1];
const char * fnmImageOut = argv [2];

av_register_all ();

// [] Open the file
AVFormatContext * pcxFormat;
if (avformat_open_input (&pcxFormat, fnmVideoIn, NULL, NULL)) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Could not open file %s for reading\n",
            fnmVideoIn);
    return -1;
}

// [] Get stream information
if (avformat_find_stream_info (pcxFormat, NULL) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Could not find stream info\n");
    return -1;
}

// [log] print stream info
av_dump_format (pcxFormat, 0, fnmVideoIn, 0);
```

and all is well. The program runs without errors and dumps the video info properly. but then I got to the next step...

```
...
// [log] print stream info
av_dump_format (pcxFormat, 0, fnmVideoIn, 0);

int ixVideoStream = -1, ixStrm;
for (ixStrm = 0; ixStrm < pcxFormat->nb_streams; ++ixStrm) {
    if (pcxFormat->streams [ixStrm]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        ixVideoStream = ixStrm;
        break;
    }
}
```

and it exits with a segfault. gdb says:

```
(gdb) r test.mp4 out
...
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb7f572c5 in avformat_open_input () from /usr/lib/libavformat.so.53
```

how is it possible that `avformat_open_input` segfaults because of code added *after* it is called? I even tested it with a regular i=0; i<100 for-loop and it still segfaults! is this a bug? For reference, my system is:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.7.0 20120414 (prerelease)

$ uname -srvmpio
Linux 3.3.4-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Apr 28 06:04:27 UTC 2012 i686 Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU P7450 @ 2.13GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux

$ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 0.10.2
built on Mar 17 2012 08:53:01 with gcc 4.6.3
configuration: --prefix=/usr --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-libvpx --enable-libtheora --enable-libgsm --enable-libspeex --enable-postproc --enable-shared --enable-x11grab --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libpulse --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --disable-debug --disable-static
libavutil      51. 35.100 / 51. 35.100
libavcodec     53. 61.100 / 53. 61.100
libavformat    53. 32.100 / 53. 32.100
libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
libavfilter     2. 61.100 /  2. 61.100
libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
libswresample   0.  6.100 /  0.  6.100
libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
```

Comment: try use `gcc -g -O0` to compile the code and run gdb to print the full backtrace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure of the etiquette on questions whose solutions were found elsewhere, but I'll self-answer here anyway, for posterity.

Anyway, the first argument to `avformat_open_input` is a pointer to a pointer to an `AVFormatContext` structure allocated using `avformat_alloc_context`, or if you want the function to allocate it for you, a null pointer.

Here, I've made the mistake of providing the function with an *uninitialized pointer*, which triggers the occasional segmentation fault errors. The connection with the for-loop was only incidental, and probably has something to do with how the compiler structures the resulting machine code.

Comment: but the examples here also doesn't initialize the pointer [http://ffmpeg.mplayerhq.hu/doxygen/trunk/filtering_8c-source.html](http://ffmpeg.mplayerhq.hu/doxygen/trunk/filtering_8c-source.html)

Comment: The initialization rules are probably different for static global variables. In any case, this is very compiler-dependent and you should initialize anyway just to be on the safe side.